# Selenium: How to get text, not HTML source?

Tags: c#, html, selenium

I am using C#, .NET 5 preview, Microsoft SQLServer 2019, Selenium.WebDriver 3.141.0, Selenium.WebDRiver.GeckoDriver 0.26.0.3 . I have

[image]

source code:

```cs
IWebElement job_work = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("pv-top-card--experience-list-item"));
IWebElement headJob = job_work.FindElement(By.TagName("span"));
Console.WriteLine("head_job: " + headJob.GetAttribute("innerHTML").Trim());
```

HTML source

```
<span id="ember93" class="text-align-left ml2 t-14 t-black t-bold full-width lt-line-clamp lt-line-clamp--multi-line ember-view" style="-webkit-line-clamp: 2">  Nordic Coder

<!----></span>
```

But it print/return result

```
Nordic Coder

<!---->
```

I want result is

```
Nordic Coder
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

use

```cs
profile.ProfileHeadJob = headJob.GetAttribute("innerText").Trim();
```

not

```cs
profile.ProfileHeadJob = headJob.GetAttribute("innerHTML").Trim();
```